# Miniaturized Chrome by AppleScript but failed

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I have tried to use `set "visible" = false`

and

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
set miniaturized of every window to true
end tell
```

Both methods work for Safari, but not for Chrome. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the correct AppleScript terms for Safari, but the terms are different for Chrome (`minimized` instead of `miniaturized`). You can inspect the AppleScript dictionary using your script editor to find the correct terms. Or you can, as I did, do

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    properties of window 1
end tell
```

to return the various properties of a window to give you clues. An example of working AppleScript code is below.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set minimized of every window to true
end tell
```